# How to use python-installed packages in web2py?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, python-imaging-library, web2py

I am running a server on amazon EC2 with web2py installed running under python2.6. In my project, I have multiple functions involving image processing that requires Python Imaging Library, which I have installed using

```
pip install pil
```

The installation is successful, and the files are in folder **usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages**

I can run the following code in python shell

```
import Image
import _imaging
```

However, if I do this inside web2py, an "import error" is returned. Instead, I can do this

```
from PIL import Image
```

but not this

```
from PIL import _imaging
```

And further Image.thumbnail() function returns

```
"no _imaging C module is installed"
```

yet, this runs normally inside shell.

It seems the modules are not registered with Web2py but only python2.6. This is very strange since web2py runs on python2.6.

Can someone help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is your Python path.  Using a debugger, or just printing results to the web2py server log, see what's in your path and if it matches your expectations:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Web2py does change up the Python path, so you may not be getting the libraries/versions you think.